# Is there a shortcut to convert an OEM windows 8 install to the Action Pack licenced version?

Tags: windows

Is there a way to convert an OEM windows 8 installation to the version that will work with Action Pack keys without reinstalling from scratch?

(I need to do this in order to upgrade Windows 8 to Windows Pro 8)?

PS This is not a licencing question

Comment: I think he might be asking about: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2750773, but maybe not.  James you should clarify your question.

Comment: Because it is not an issue of whether I am licenced to use windows (which would be out of scope) but how to activate the right version (which is in scope)

Comment: I've edited the question, clearer now?

Answer (score 3):

It turned out to be much easier than I expected. **After** I had applied all outstanding windows updates, anytime upgrade accepted the action pack keys and just did it.